# Incorrect data in funnels

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-remote-config

I log two differnt events for two groups of users. They are specified in remote config (50% of random percintile). The events shouldnt appear both for one user but they overlap in funnels. What can bo done wrong?

```
OnCompleteListener<Void> onCompleteListener = new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();



                    Boolean shuldShowPremiumDialoginNotification = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getBoolean("premiumDialogInNotifications");
                    KLog.e(shuldShowPremiumDialoginNotification);
                    SharedPrefsManager.setShowPremiumDialogInNotifiactions(SettingsActivity.this, shuldShowPremiumDialoginNotification);
                    if (shuldShowPremiumDialoginNotification)
                        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("premium_dialog_show_T", null);
                    else
                        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("premium_dialog_show_F", null);


                } else KLog.e("remote config error " + task.getException().getMessage());
            }
        };

        if (mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getInfo().getConfigSettings().isDeveloperModeEnabled()) {
            // This forces Remote Config to fetch from server every time.
            mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(0).addOnCompleteListener(this, onCompleteListener);
        } else {
            mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch().addOnCompleteListener(this, onCompleteListener);
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong -- I think the important thing to understand is that funnels in Firebase Analytics are "open" funnels, and not closed funnels. Meaning that they're really not "How many people encountered event A and then encountered event B" kinds of graphs -- they're more like, "Let's just show event A and event B side-by-side" kinds of reports.

And so that's what you're seeing here. Approximately 745 of your users saw the dialog_T event, and 776 of your users say the dialog_F event, which pretty much exactly matches up with what you'd expect to see with your Remote Config setup.